# replace string if a condition is satisfied in python

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this,  if docket ="3ghi" (i could be "3ghi" or 5"ghi" )in the file then condition is greater than 4 should be changed to "new" and condition <=2 should be changed to "fair" . I added my code below, the replace command works but my if loop is bad. Please help.

```
Input:
<code=report docket="3ghi" parse=20>
    <items="20" product="abc" condition="9">
    <items="50" product="xyz" condition="8">
    <items="" product="mno" condition="2">

Output:
<code=report docket="3ghi" parse=20>
    <items="20" product="abc" condition="new">
    <items="50" product="xyz" condition="new">
    <items="" product="mno" condition="fair">

with open(("test.txt",'r') as new:
   readin = new.read
   if "docket =3ghi" == True:
        readin.replace('condition="4-100"', 'condition="new"')
        readin.replace('condition="1-2"', 'condition="fair"')
        x.write(readin)
```

Comment: All non empty string will default to `True`. Use something like `"3ghi" in block`

Comment: All told, if you are parsing xml, it's best to use an xml parser like the [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which is built-in, or a third party package like [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/). Parsers make structured languages like xml and html *much* easier to process

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

```
readin = new.read
```

You're not calling the method, you won't get the file contents in `readin`

Second problem:

```
if "docket =3ghi" == True:
```

You're comparing if a string is `True` - it's never `True`.

Comment: A non-empty string is always `True`

Comment: @Javier `str == bool` *is* never `True`

Comment: @Javier That only works if you're trying to use the string itself as the condition. `if string` will be true is `string` is non-empty

Comment: Good answer, though it may be worth noting that `bool` can be used to convert `"docket =3ghi"` to a boolean so it can be evaluated as expected in the if statement.

Comment: It is worth noting all these considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your current statement:

```py
if "docket = 3ghi" == True:
```

Non-empty strings evaluate like `True`, but are not *exactly* `True`. `True` is a boolean, so you are asking "is this string a boolean?" That is always `False`:

```py
"somestr" == True
# False
```

Fix it to check if the string is `in` a part of a file. For example:

```py
with open(("test.txt",'r') as new:
    for line in new.read(): # read in the file and iterate
         if "somestr" in line:
             # do something
```

Note I've also added the parens to `new.read()` so that you don't get exceptions like `function doesn't support iteration`

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is reading the file using the read, its a method.

```
new.read()
```

Secondly, you're checking if

```
"docket=3ghi"
```

exist in the file, thats not how its done. You ought to have iterated first e.g

```
for i in reading:
    if "your string" in i:
        print("Put your action here")
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly call the method to have the whole content of the file in `readin`. Now you can `replace` twice checking also correctly the condition

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as new:
    readin = new.read()
    if 'docket="3ghi"' in readin:
        readin = readin.replace('"I"', '"new"').replace('"II"', '"fair"')
        # save or print or do whatever you want with readin
```

Comment: How can i edit this to replace anything above 2 to "fair" .  for example <items="20" product="abc" condition="2">

Comment: What above 2? items?

Comment: If the condition is above 2, im sorry for not being clear, I updated the question to reflect my explanation

Comment: You can still concatenate more `.replace()`. Not a very elegant or eficient solution if you have too many more numbers, though. In that case, you should explore doing a substitution using regular expressions rather than `replace`.